# Cassandra query table based on row range

Tags: cassandra

I am new to cassandra. I am using cassandra-3.0 and datastax java driver for development. I would like to know whether cassandra provide any option to fecth the data based on rowkey range?

something like

```
select * from <table-name> where rowkey > ? and rowkey < ?;
```

If not, is there any other option in cassandra ( java/cql) to fetchdata based on row ranges?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there really isn't a mechanism in Cassandra that works in the way that you are asking.  The only way to run a range query on your partition keys (rowkey) is with the `token` function.  This is because Cassandra orders its rows in the cluster by the hashed token value of the partition key.  That value would not really have any meaning for you, but it would allow you to "page" through the a large table without encountering timeouts.

```
SELECT * FROM <table-name>
WHERE token(rowkey) > -9223372036854775807
AND token(rowkey) < -5534023222112865485;
```

The way to go about range querying on meaningful values, is to find a value to partition your rows by, and then cluster by a numeric or time value.  For example, I can query a table of events by date range, if I partition my data by `month` (`PRIMARY KEY(month,eventdate)`):

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM events 
    WHERE monthbucket='201509' 
    AND eventdate > '2015-09-19' AND eventdate < '2015-09-26';

 monthbucket | eventdate                | beginend | eventid                              | eventname
-------------+--------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+------------------------
      201509 | 2015-09-25 06:00:00+0000 |        B | a223ad16-2afd-4213-bee3-08a2c4dd63e6 |             Hobbit Day
      201509 | 2015-09-25 05:59:59+0000 |        E | 9cd6a265-6c60-4537-9ea9-b57e7c152db9 |       Cassandra Summit
      201509 | 2015-09-22 06:00:00+0000 |        B | 9cd6a265-6c60-4537-9ea9-b57e7c152db9 |       Cassandra Summit
      201509 | 2015-09-20 05:59:59+0000 |        E | b9fe9668-cef2-464e-beb4-d4f985ef9c47 | Talk Like a Pirate Day
      201509 | 2015-09-19 06:00:00+0000 |        B | b9fe9668-cef2-464e-beb4-d4f985ef9c47 | Talk Like a Pirate Day

(5 rows)
```